# How to use SPSS output for calculating additional variable by syntax?

Tags: spss

I need to use the output from certain tests like Factor Analysis to compute additional variable like socioeconomic status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some features of factor analysis, such as factor scores variables or factor loading matrix, you can save right from FACTOR command. To save other statistics, use OMS-OMSEND facility which automatically saves content of user-specified output tables as data. "Utilities" menu items OMS Control Panel and OMS Identifiers will aid you to customize your request for saving.